# An example of Sobolev function.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces

How can I prove that the function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$:

$$f(x) = \sin(\log |\log |x||)$$

belongs to $W^{1,n}(B_r(0)),\, r>0,\, 0\neq x \in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus \partial B_1(0)$.

---

In the norm of the $ f $ derivative I tried some approximation but was unsuccessful.

Comment: It seems to me that if you differentiate and then integrate using polar coordinates, that you end up with it being bounded above by  $C \int_0^r \frac{d\rho}{(\rho \log|\rho|)^n} \, d\rho$.

Comment: I meant $C \int_0^r \frac{d\rho}{\rho(\log|\rho|)^n} $.

Comment: To the power of $1/n$.